# How to insert a pdf into specific area in my page

Tags: pdftex

I generally insert a PDF in a full page using

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\includepdfmerge[fitpaper]{./test.pdf, 10}
```

The above inserts the page completely with the PDF page.

I want to insert the PDF only into a small box within my page.

How can I do it?

What I want is as below: (but I want the text in my PDF to be searchable also). I don't want to insert it like an image.

[image]

Comment: Use \includegraphics[page=10]{test}.

Comment: Ok. I will try that.

Comment: I started using \includegraphics but the file sizes are significantly larger. I have asked a question regarding this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562575/pdflatex-filesize-of-pdf-generated-using-includepdfmergepdf-pages-is-much-sma