# pdflatex: filesize of pdf generated using includepdfmerge(pdf-pages) is much smaller that includegraphics

Tags: pdftex, pdfpages, includegraphics

I have a pdf file `test.pdf`. I am regenerating the same pdf using two different methods `includepdfmerge` and `includegraphics`. I found that pdf generated using `includepdfmerge` is almost same as original pdf where as pdf generated using `includegraphics` is 3-4 times larger than the original file. The below is the latex code and also attached the link for the files.

**METHOD1: using includepdfmerge**

OUTPUT FILENAME: test_includepdf.pdf

The script is adding 5 pages from test.pdf

```
\documentclass[version=3.21]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=false,footsepline=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 33.87999pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm}
\includepdfmerge[fitpaper,templatesize={432pt}{33.87999pt}]{test.pdf, 1}
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 33.87999pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm}
\includepdfmerge[fitpaper,templatesize={432pt}{33.87999pt}]{test.pdf, 2}
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 33.87999pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm}
\includepdfmerge[fitpaper,templatesize={432pt}{33.87999pt}]{test.pdf, 3}
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 33.87999pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm}
\includepdfmerge[fitpaper,templatesize={432pt}{33.87999pt}]{test.pdf, 4}
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 33.87999pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm}
\includepdfmerge[fitpaper,templatesize={432pt}{33.87999pt}]{test.pdf, 5}
\end{document}
```

**METHOD2: using includegraphics**

OUTPUT FILENAME: test_includegraphics.pdf

The script is adding 5 pages from test.pdf

```
\documentclass[parskip=full,version=3.21]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=false,footsepline=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:33.87999pt,DIV=calc}%
\recalctypearea%
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 33.87999pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm}%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio,page=1]{test.pdf}%
\KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:33.87999pt,DIV=calc}%
\recalctypearea%
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 33.87999pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm}%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio,page=2]{test.pdf}%
\KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:33.87999pt,DIV=calc}%
\recalctypearea%
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 33.87999pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm}%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio,page=3]{test.pdf}%
\KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:33.87999pt,DIV=calc}%
\recalctypearea%
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 33.87999pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm}%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio,page=4]{test.pdf}%
\KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:33.87999pt,DIV=calc}%
\recalctypearea%
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 33.87999pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm}%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio,page=5]{test.pdf}%
\end{document}
```

All the files are available at the link https://filebin.net/1498hwp3fxnngpcs
Note:The above link will get expired by Sep-20-2020

The file sizes i got are:

```
 test.pdf   19 kB
 test_includepdf.pdf    20 kB
 test_includegraphics.pdf   76 kB
```

As we see that `test_includegrahicps.pdf` is significantly larger than the `test.pdf` and `test_includepdf.pdf`

Why the second script with includegraphics produce large pdfs sizes. Is there any way i can control the size.

Because if i try on a pdf with `1000` pages, then using `includepdf` filesize is `1MB` and using `includegrahicps` is `11MB`

**TEMPORARY WORKAROUND**

CURRENTLY BASED ON SOME TRAIL AND ERROR, I COULD MAKE THE FILE SIZE SMALLER USING combination of `includepdf` and `includegraphics`. This is not the right solution but solves to some extent my need

I could not figure out the reason for my question.

But Because i have to use includegraphics in my latex project and at the same time i dont want huge file sizes, by doing trail and error i figured out the following way which will produce less significantly less file size

Add an additional first page in the pdf which will be called using `\includepdfmerge` and then the rest of the pages can be called using `includegraphics`

So i tried

```
\documentclass[parskip=full,version=3.21]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=false,footsepline=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\color[RGB]{84,84,84}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{0pt}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%% ADDITIONAL PAGE IN THE START CALLED USING includepdfmerge
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 33.87999pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm}
\includepdfmerge[fitpaper,templatesize={432pt}{33.87999pt}]{test.pdf, 1}
%%%%%%  LATER PAGES CALLED USING INCLUDEGRAPHICS
\KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:38.87999pt,DIV=calc}%
\recalctypearea%
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 38.87999pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm}%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio,page=1]{test.pdf}%
\KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:38.87999pt,DIV=calc}%
\recalctypearea%
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 38.87999pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm}%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio,page=2]{test.pdf}%
\KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:38.87999pt,DIV=calc}%
\recalctypearea%
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 38.87999pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm}%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio,page=3]{test.pdf}%
\KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:38.87999pt,DIV=calc}%
\recalctypearea%
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 38.87999pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm}%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio,page=4]{test.pdf}%
\KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:38.87999pt,DIV=calc}%
\recalctypearea%
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 38.87999pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm}%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio,page=5]{test.pdf}%
\end{document}
```

**The following is the change:**

```
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 33.87999pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm}
\includepdfmerge[fitpaper,templatesize={432pt}{33.87999pt}]{test.pdf, 1}
```

Added \includepdfmerge in the beginning page and later pages using `includegraphics`

```
\KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:38.87999pt,DIV=calc}%
\recalctypearea%
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 38.87999pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm}%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio,page=1]{test.pdf}%
```

The final pdf file has one extra page in the beginning

NOw the file size is `20kb`. The following link is the final output pdf

https://filebin.net/5p2a32kdx80qmvni

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be enough to store the pdf once in temporary box to trigger the font optimization. It is needed only with pdflatex, lualatex does it by default.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
\setbox\@tempboxa=\hbox{\includegraphics{example-image-a4-numbered}}% font is included only once
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio,page=1]{example-image-a4-numbered}%
\newpage
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio,page=2]{example-image-a4-numbered}%
\newpage
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio,page=3]{example-image-a4-numbered}%
\newpage
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio,page=4]{example-image-a4-numbered}%
\newpage
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio,page=5]{example-image-a4-numbered}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: I never used lualatex. I will try this

Comment: Works like a charm. Can i also add multiple pdfs. For gathering more fonts before

Comment: Can you explain the syntax `\setbox\@tempboxa=\hbox{}` How this store the pdf in temporary box.  I am new to this

Comment: Recently i was doing lot of pdf manipulation. I found about pdflatex and learned about KOMA script, pdfpages, includegraphics which is what I play with for my task. After this answer `45MB pdf size is now 15.1MB significant reduction in size`. (its 12,000 pages and avg page size of 6"x6"). So thank you again

Answer (score 2):

***ANSWER PART1: WHY THE FILE SIZE IF BIG when only using includegraphics***

It is due to fonts embedded mutlitple times

FIle made using only `includegraphics`

```
$ pdffonts test_includegraphics.pdf 
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
ABCDEE+ScaGoudy                      TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no       9  0
ABCDEE+ScaGoudy                      TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no      19  0
ABCDEE+ScaGoudy                      TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no      31  0
ABCDEE+ScaGoudy                      TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no      41  0
ABCDEE+ScaGoudy                      TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no      51  0
```

File made using only `includepdfmerge`

```
$ pdffonts test_includepdf.pdf 
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
ABCDEE+ScaGoudy                      TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no      12  0
```

FILE made using first page `includepdfmerge` and rest using `includegraphics`

```
$ pdffonts test_mix.pdf       
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
ABCDEE+ScaGoudy                      TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no      15  0
```

As it can seen the font is embedded `5 times` when i used only `includegraphics` where other two cases only `once`

**NO ANSWER FOUND FOR PART2: HOW TO AVOID IT**

`But now the question is how can we avoid font getting embedded mutliple times when made using only includegraphics`

I found a similar question:

[Same font embedded twice when including graphics created with standalone](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83671/same-font-embedded-twice-when-including-graphics-created-with-standalone)

One of the answer says using latex its not possible. Only way is to do it later using `pdfsizeopt`  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83709/221200

Also tried suggested solution `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=0`, but it does not work, or fonts gets embedded mutliple times in pdflatex